# Custom data type to string conversion in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I'm trying to solve this problem where I'll have to put other variables inside `string acc`, but I don 't know how to do that. Tried with creating a custom data type and converting it to string but that's not working.

Can anyone help me with this ?

This is the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wReLU.jpg

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Person
        {
            private string name;
            private string dob;

            public Person()
            {
            }

            public Person(string name, string dob)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.dob = dob;
            }

            public void setName(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public void setDob(string dob)
            {
                this.dob = dob;
            }

            public string getName()
            {
                return name;
            }

            public string getDob()
            {
                return dob;
            }
        }

        struct Account
        {
            public int account_id;
            public double amount;
            public string accType;
        }

        class Employee : Person
        {
            private string name;
            private string dob;
            public Account account;
            private string acc;

            public Employee()
            {
            }

            public Employee(string name, string dob, string acc)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.dob = dob;
                this.acc = acc;
            }

            public void setAcc(string acc)
            {
                this.acc = acc;
            }

            public void display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + getName());
                Console.WriteLine("Date of birth: " + getDob());
                Console.WriteLine("Account Id: " + account.account_id);
                Console.WriteLine("Amount: " + account.amount);
                Console.WriteLine("Account Type: " + account.accType);
            }
        }

        class Customer : Person
        {
            private string name;
            private string dob;
            public Account account;
            private string acc;

            public Customer()
            {
            }

            public Customer(string name, string dob, string acc)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.dob = dob;
                this.acc = acc;
            }

            public void setAcc(string acc)
            {
                this.acc = acc;
            }

            public void display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + getName());
                Console.WriteLine("Date of birth: " + getDob());
                Console.WriteLine("Account Id: " + account.account_id);
                Console.WriteLine("Amount: " + account.amount);
                Console.WriteLine("Account Type: " + account.accType);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Account account;

            account.account_id = 7478126;
            account.amount = 12000;
            account.accType = "Savings";
            string act = Convert.ToString(account);

            Employee em = new Employee();
            Console.WriteLine("Employee details:");
            em.setName("L");
            em.setDob("11.11.1999");
            em.setAcc(act);
            em.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're writing C# as if it were Java.

Comment: String can be combine with a plus sign : string C = "A" + "B";  Or even better use string format : string C = string.Format("string A = {0}, string B = {1}", a, b);

Comment: `that' s not working` how does it not working?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Introduction to Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes) and [Explore object oriented programming with classes and objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/classes). Unless your assignment requires it, use a `class` instead of a [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct).

Comment: Use [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Also see [How to override the ToString method (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Comment: also lookup string interpolation - ie `string foo = $"x={x}";`

Comment: Just a handy hint when designing what looks to be a bank account balance: don't implement a `double amount` field (it should be `decimal`, but don't implement that either). Instead have a list of transactions and compute the balance from that list. It's too easy to make a mistake when updating a single field and you will lose your balance - and customers hate that kind of thing. A verifiable list of transactions ensures that the balance is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements you have are awful. They make you use Java style method, even though you're writing C#. And they are prescribing an inheritance structure (diagram) but the code itself doesn't use that structure. And they make you use inappropriate types.

You've introduced an `struct Account` even though the requirements do not mention using such a structure.

Here's how it possibly should be written:

```
abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateOnly Dob { get; private set; }
    public string Account { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, DateOnly dob, string account)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Dob = dob;
        this.Account = account;
    }

    public override string ToString() =>
        String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            new []
            {
                $"Name: {this.Name}",
                $"Date of birth: {this.Dob.ToShortDateString()}",
                $"Account Type: {this.Account}",
            });
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public Employee(string name, DateOnly dob, string account)
        : base(name, dob, account) { }
}

class Customer : Person
{
    public Customer(string name, DateOnly dob, string account)
        : base(name, dob, account) { }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee em = new Employee("L", new DateOnly(1999, 11, 11), "Savings");
    Console.WriteLine("Employee details:");
    Console.WriteLine(em.ToString());
}
```